# SQL UPDATE statement with LEFT JOIN, GROUP BY and HAVING?

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax, sql-update

I need to update some rows in a table. I've created a Select statement to make sure I've got the rows I wanted to select.

I want to update task_status_id in the table task, and I've tried in various ways but always end up with a syntax error and have honestly no idea how to do so even though I've tried to follow others examples by using INNER JOIN and putting the select statement in parenthesis. Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE statement to merge with the SELECT statement.

```
UPDATE task
SET task_status_id =  (SELECT task_status_id
                                FROM task_status
                                WHERE task_type_id = 1
                                AND name = 'Completed');
```

**WHERE**

```
SELECT
    t.task_id
FROM task t
         LEFT JOIN user u
                   ON t.user_id = u.user_id
         LEFT JOIN contract co
                   ON u.user_id = co.user_id
        LEFT JOIN task_status ts
            ON t.task_status_id = ts.task_status_id
WHERE co.status = 'Closed' AND
        t.task_type_id = 1 AND
      t.task_status_id != (SELECT task_status_id
                                FROM task_status
                                WHERE task_type_id = 1
                                AND name = 'Completed')
GROUP BY t.task_id
HAVING count(t.contract_id) <= 2;
```

Comment: First: get rid of the (non)scalar subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it doesn't make sense to use `LEFT JOIN contract co` and then filter results using `co.status = 'Closed'`, because if you're going to filter by a column from a joined table then you should use `INNER JOIN` (unless you're comparing to `null` in the filter).

Secondly, syntax here is incorrect - you should use `not in` instead of `!=`

```
  AND t.task_status_id != (SELECT task_status_id
                            FROM task_status
                            WHERE task_type_id = 1
                            AND name = 'Completed')
```

However, since you already joined the `task_status` table you can replace the above block of code with the following (assuming that `task_status_id` is a unique column):

```
AND ts.name != 'Completed'
```

Either way, you should post sample data and expected result.